# Problems with React Router/Hoook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-hooks

**Update (new changes):**
So now I pretty much converted my code to a functional component however it is as if nothing is being returned from the API, or perhaps I am not "mounting" correctly? I get the error " TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" meaning nothing is being returned but I'm not sure why. Help?

**Old post (I had previously tried to use a hook in a a class component):**

I'm pretty brand new to react and recently I have been getting this error from when trying to navigate to a page on click of a card media (using material ui). So I pretty much follow the instruction to push to history the route to the page I want to navigate to via a function and call that function when I click the media card. Below is my code and the error I get. Do you have any idea why I might be having an issue with this?

**My updated code**

```
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import {getItems} from "../Network/network_utility";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    icon: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    heroContent: {
        padding: theme.spacing(8, 0, 6),
    },
    cardGrid: {
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(6),
        paddingBottom: theme.spacing(3),
        position: "fixed"
    }
}));

export default function Items() {

    let history = useHistory();
    const classes = useStyles();

    const useFeaturedItems = () => {
        const [featured_items, setFeaturedItems] = useState([]);
        useEffect(() => {
            getItems(1).then(response => setFeaturedItems(response["data"]))}, []);
        return featured_items;
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Container className={classes.cardGrid} maxWidth="lg">
                <Grid container spacing={6}>
                    {useFeaturedItems().map((card, index) => (
                        <Grid item key={index} xs={16} sm={4} md={2}>
                            <Card raised={false} style={{height: "30vh", width: "20vh"}}>
                                <CardMedia
                                    component="img"
                                    src={card["thumbnail"]}
                                    style={{height: "25vh", width: "20vh"}}
                                    onClick={history.push("/item")}
                                >
                                </CardMedia>
                                <div style={{paddingLeft: "10px", paddingTop: "10px"}}>
                                    <text style={{
                                        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                                        overflow: "hidden",
                                        display: "block",
                                        textOverflow: "ellipsis"
                                    }}>
                                        {card["title"]}
                                    </text>
                                </div>
                            </Card>
                        </Grid>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You are using a class based component but hooks are only supported in functional component. I hope you have already gone through the documentation before using hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are using hook inside a class component. It is not possibile

[how use hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both)

> You can’t use Hooks inside a class component, but you can definitely mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single tree. Whether a component is a class or a function that uses Hooks is an implementation detail of that component. In the longer term, we expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components.

In class component you need to use the HOC withRouter. After that you can access the history through props with this.props.history